# Cannot see documents by hitting TemplateApi endpoint

Tags: java, spring-boot, docusignapi

I am trying to get all the documents that I created from the docusign website by calling TemplateApi, but I got an empty list of docs:

```
"deliveredDateTime": null,
"description": "My first template",
"documents": [],
"documentsCombinedUri": null,
"documentsUri": null
```

I have 2 PDF docs in that template, very straight forward code to get all templates:

```
public TemplateDocumentsResult templateDocs(String templateId) throws ApiException {
    ApiClient apiClient = baseRestApiClient();
    apiClient.addDefaultHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + getToken());
    TemplatesApi templateApi = new TemplatesApi(apiClient);

    return templateApi.listDocuments(accountId, templateId);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

can you try to use POSTMAN to make the raw API Call like this:

```
GET /v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/templates/{templateId}/documents
```

This would isolate if this is an issue with the C# SDK or is that an issue with the API

Also, can you confirm you are using version 4.0.0 of the Nuget